# AutoMapping custom Generic Types - How?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-3.5, automapper

hey guys, I'm using [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) version 1.1.0.188

In my AutoMapper.Configure I'm mapping Entities to DTOs and vice versa, like so:

```
// entity >> DTO
Mapper.CreateMap<MetaTemplate, MetaTemplateDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>();     

// DTO >> Entity
Mapper.CreateMap<MetaTemplateDTO, MetaTemplate>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>();
```

When I do the below mappings (and vice versa) everything works fine

```
Mapper.Map<entity, entityDTO>(entity);

Mapper.Map<List<entity>, List<entityDTO>>(entities);
```

Note above that automapper just works with List<> without me having to configure anything.

I have a Generic Container (simplified for this example):

```
public class Container<T>
{
    public int TotalItems{get;set;}
    public IList<T> Items{get;set;}
}
```

Now, without any extra automapping config, when I do:

```
Mapper.Map<Container<entity>, Container<entityDTO>>(entityContainer);
```

I get an automapper exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.Exception

However, if I add this line in the automap configure for a specific type, as below, then the Container mapping works.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Container<PersonDTO>, Container<Person>>();
```

However, it will ONLY work for that Person/PersonDTO type.

Why is this? How can I make automapper recognize the Container class as it recognizes List<>??

I don't want to explicitly configure mappings for every type AGAIN.

cool, cheers

Comment: I don't know how to accomplish this with AutoMapper but have you tried EmitMapper (http://emitmapper.codeplex.com)? With EmitMapper this mapping can be done with 0 configuration if you change the type of Container<T>.Items to List<T>.

Comment: you mean it's the IList thats the issue?

Comment: No, I meant that with EmitMapper you could do this mapping without configaration at all provided that you change the type of Container.Items to List<T>.

Comment: ahh... ok, interesting. I think for the current project that won't happen, but I'll take a look at it, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that Automapper just doesn't deal with unsupported types, even if the Type you're using is a container of supported types.

The solution was to map the object manually

Answer (score 2):

If your generic container class behaves like a list of objects then you may be best off implementing the IEnumerable interface. Then the automapper should be able to iterate through the objects and map them accordingly.

Comment: hmm... interesting suggestion, I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: nope didn't work. just tried it and implementing all of IEnumerable didn't work. weirdly, as I say above, if I explicitly map.CreateMap Container<T> to Container<T1> it works fine... which is weird??

Comment: That's the expected behaviour, the automapper can only map what it knows about

Comment: After reading the code you need to implement IList instead of IEnumerable - check out http://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/EnumerableMapper.cs

Comment: You may want to also read http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/cec579c8d249c1c5?pli=1