# Linq to Entities convert one entity to similar

Tags: vb.net, linq, entities

I have an Entity model with entities of `Person` and `LogPerson`. they are identical except that `LogPerson` has 2 additional fields (`LogPersonID`, `CreateDate`). How can I **cast** a `LogPerson` into a `Person` so that the VB.NET code that follows my Linq code doesn't have to try to work with both possible types?

For example:

```
dim p as person
If useLog then
   p = From a In LogPerson Where ID = x
Else
   p = From a In Person Where ID = x
End If

textbox1.text = p.firstname
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is "auto-map". [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074617/automapping-custom-generic-types-how) might be of some help.

Comment: No, just work with a particular table in a particular circumstance (view from log, view active record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any ways out-of-the box.  The easiest way without third party tools/libraries is to use the [`Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) and map the properties manually, like so:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = ...;

IEnumerable<LogPerson> logPeople = people.Select(p => new LogPerson { 
    Name = p.Name,
    Age = p.Age,
    ...
});
```

Of course, this is tedious, so if you have a large number of fields or a number of places you have to perform this kind of operation, you might want to look into an auto mapping library, such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Answer (score 0):

```
I am WRITING THE SOLUTION IN C#....

person p;
if(uselog)
{
var per = from pobj in LogPerson
          where pobj.ID= x
          select new person{
          firstname = pobj.firstname,
          lastname = pobj.lastname,
          };
}else
{
var per = from pobj in Person
    where pobj.ID= x
    select new person{
    firstname = pobj.firstname,
    lastname = pobj.lastname,
    };
}
p = per.first();
}


textbox1.text = p.firstname
```